# Solutions to simultaneous Diophantine equations $2y^2-3x^2=-1$ and $z^2-2y^2= -1$

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, systems-of-equations, pell-type-equations

> I am looking for integer solutions for the following set of equations:
>
> $2y^2-3x^2=-1$
>
> $z^2-2y^2= -1$

I know that there are the solutions (1,1,1) and (-1,-1,-1) for this set of simultaneous equations.
How would I go about showing that there are no other solutions to these simultaneous equations?

Comment: Seems the duplicate of [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1033171/269624)

Answer (score 1):

There are no integer solutions other than the trivial $\lvert x \rvert = \lvert y \rvert = \lvert z \lvert = 1.$

An elementary solution can be found at [this earlier (duplicate) post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1752147/93271).