# What triples of square-free integers $(r,s,t)$ admit integer solutions $(x,y,z)$ where $rx^2,sy^2,tz^2$ are consecutive integers?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, square-numbers, pell-type-equations

In [this post on the consecutive integers $b^2,2a^2,3c^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1033171/does-this-system-of-simultaneous-pell-like-equations-have-any-non-trivial-positi), I asked whether the trivial solution $a=b=c=1$ was the only one. At this time, that question appears to have been answered in the affirmative (proven by @san).

Now my question is a generalization, which may or may not already have an answer (cf. Erdős's study of consecutive integers and their factors, powerful numbers, *etc.*):

**QUESTION:** For which triples of square-free integers $(r,s,t)$ do triples of integers $(x,y,z)$ exist such that $rx^2$, $sy^2$, and $tz^2$ are consecutive integers?

Example: The question referenced at the top of this post is the special case $(r,s,t)=(1,2,3)$, for which the only solution triple $(x,y,z)$ is the trivial solution $(x,y,z)=(1,1,1)$, leading to the consecutive integers $$(rx^2,sy^2,tz^2)=(1,2,3).$$

Has this problem already been tackled? Obviously there are many tools by which it can be attacked (*e.g.*, complete solutions to the equation $uX^2+vY^2+wZ^2=0$).

Comment: @NobleMushtak: Yes. I've edited the question and title to try to make that more clear.

Comment: OK, thanks for the clarification. Also, $r, s, t$ are square-free or just not perfect squares?

Comment: @NobleMushtak: I wanted to leave it more open, but I'll lock it down completely.