# Solving a pair of simultaneous Pell-like equations

Tags: elementary-number-theory, systems-of-equations, diophantine-equations, pell-type-equations

I'm trying to prove the following.

> **Conjecture:** If $a,b,c$ are positive integers satisfying the system of equations
>   \begin{align}
>   a^2+3b^2 &= 4c^2,  \\
>   a^2-3b^2 &= -2,
> \end{align}
>   then $(a,b,c)=(1,1,1)$.

Unfortunately, all my efforts have ended up going around in circles. I’m assuming there’s a relatively easy proof (likely by descent). Any suggestions/hints would be appreciated.

Comment: This is the [same problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1033171/464638) you once posted 3 years ago.

Comment: @Hellen: Really? (Talk about going around in circles!!!) How can I show they’re equivalent?

Comment: The new $a$ is the old $b$, the new $b$ is the old $c$.

Comment: @Hellen: What's the new [constant] 1? And that one has 2s where this one has 3s, right?

Comment: The old system is, with variables names replaced to avoid confusion, 
\begin{align}
2x^2-1 &= y^2,  \\
2x^2+1 &= 3z^2.
\end{align}Now put $y=a$, $x=c$, and $z=b$.The system becomes \begin{align}
2c^2-1 &= a^2,  \\
2c^2+1 &= 3b^2.
\end{align}
Replace $2c^2$ from the first equation into the second to get $a^2-2=3b^2$ or $a^2-3b^2=-2$. Now multiply by $2$ the first equation and equate $-2$ with $-2$ to get $2a^2-4c^2=a^2-3b^2$, which gives $a^2+3b^2=4c^2$.

Comment: @Hellen: Please transfer your comment to an answer (including a link to the other question) and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the [same problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1033171/464638) you once posted 3 years ago. Replacing variable names to avoid confusion, the old system is
\begin{align}
  2x^2−1 &= y^2, \\
  2x^2+1 &= 3z^2.
\end{align}
Now put $y=a$, $x=c$, and $z=b$, so that the system becomes
\begin{align}
  2c^2-1 &= a^2,  \\
  2c^2+1 &= 3b^2.
\end{align}
Substitute $2c^2=a^2+1$ (as given by the first equation) into the second to get $a^2+2=3b^2$ or $a^2−3b^2=−2$. Now multiply the first equation by $2$ and equate with $-2$ to get $2a^2-4c^2 = a^2-3b^2$, which is $a^2+3b^2=4c^2$.