# Consecutive multiples of squares

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, square-numbers

I noticed $49=1\cdot7^2$ and $50=2\cdot5^2$, and I was curious if there exists longer runs of this form. Specifically, consecutive positive integers such that the first is a square, the second is twice a square, the third is $3$ times a square, etc..

Messing around trying to find a run of $3$, I figure the first number $x$ must be odd because the second number is even, and $x$ must be one more than a multiple of $3$, because the third number is a multiple of $3$. This means the first number is one more than a multiple of $6$, and therefore square of a number one more or one less than a multiple of $6$.

Using similar logic, I figured that the second number is twice the square of a number one more or one less than a multiple of $6$, and the third number is $3$ times the square of an odd number, but that was all I was able to figure.

Any help on getting further would be great.

Edit:
Trivially, $1=1\cdot1^2, 2=2\cdot1^2, 3=3\cdot1^2, $ etc.

besides $49$ and $50$, I also found $1681=1\cdot41^2$ and $1682=2\cdot29^2$

Comment: See [A002315](https://oeis.org/A002315), whose terms $a$ satisfy $a^2 + 1 = 2b^2$, giving your runs of $2$.

Comment: @Vepir the trouble is that the condition $a^2 - 3 c^2 = -2$ demands $a$ in the sequence $1, 5, 19, 71,  ...$  with $a_{k+2} = 4 a_{k+1}  - a_k$  I don't see the sequences having any overlap other than $1$

Comment: @lulu The OP is asking, non merely that the kth number be divisible by a square, but that the kth term be k times a square.

Comment: @WillJagy That is true (there are no non-trivial runs of 3 or more). This question is equivalent to [Does this system of simultaneous Pell-like equations have any non-trivial positive integer solutions?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1033171/318073), where this result is proven.

Comment: @Vepir  it appears that the proofs there had gaps. One of those commenting with doubts is mercio, an expert...

Comment: @WillJagy There are wrong deleted answers and one incomplete answer, but there is also the accepted and bountyed answer which appears fine, I don't see anyone pointing out error(s) in the comments under it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To find all runs of $2$ terms $\{a^2,2b^2\}$, solve the [Pell(ish) equation](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PellEquation.html) $a^2 - 2b^2 = -1$.

These numbers (solutions) are already well documented in [A002315](https://oeis.org/A002315).

For instance, they satisfy $a_n = 6a_{n-1} - a_{n-2}$ and $a_n=\frac{(1+\sqrt2)^{2n+1} + (1-\sqrt2)^{2n+1}}{2}$.

They are also called [NSW Numbers](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/NSWNumber.html), starting as $a_n=1,7, 41, 239, 1393,\dots$

---

On the other hand, there are no non-trivial runs of $3$ (or more) terms.

This was proven in the following MSE question (equivalent problem): [Does this system of simultaneous Pell-like equations have any non-trivial positive integer solutions?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1033171/318073).